# Can I make a directory on OS X appear as a volume so I can backup using Super Duper?

Tags: backup, mount, sparsebundle, superduper

I use Lightroom and keep my library on an external hard drive. After I quit Lightroom I use SuperDuper! to back up that external hard drive to an identical external hard drive.

I also have two [Transporters](http://filetransporterstore.com/collections/products/products/transporter-w-1tb-drive), one on-site and another off-site. I would like to backup to the on-site Transporter. The Transporter Library shows up as a folder. I would like to create a sub-folder and then use SuperDuper! to backup to that folder.

However SuperDuper only allows you to backup to a mounted volume.[image: SuperDuper! screen]

Is there a way on OS X to make a directory appear as a volume so it would appear in the to: drop down of SuperDuper! or would the recommended way to be backup to a Sparse Bundle Disk Image located in the Transporter folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can share arbitrary folders on your Transporter you can then mount that folder across the network and SuperDuper will see it as a volume.

Failing that you may just want to create a disk image in that folder and have SuperDuper back up to that. That is how I do it with an external drive on a Mac that is always on. Several Macs back up to that drive, each to their own disk image via SuperDuper

Comment: I ended up going the route of the disk image. It seems to be working but was not intuitive initially as the way to proceed.